# Clustering points around already known cluster centers

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a set of points (~1000) and a set of cluster centers (~100). I now want to cluster the set of points taking the already known cluster centers into account. All clusters should start out from the already known cluster centers growing outwards collecting all points less than x meters away from the closest point already inside the cluster.

I now have the following pretty standard PostGIS dbscan query:

```
WITH clusters AS (
  SELECT
    landmark_id, coordinate,
    ST_ClusterDBSCAN(coordinate, eps := (30 / 111111.0), minpoints := 10) OVER() AS cluster_id
  FROM landmarks 
  WHERE coordinate IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
  cluster.id, cluster.landmark_ids,
  ST_Centroid(cluster.geometry) AS coordinate,
  ST_AsGeoJSON(cluster.geometry) AS geometry
FROM (
  SELECT
    cluster_id AS id,
    array_agg(landmark_id) AS landmark_ids,
    ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(coordinate)) AS geometry
  FROM clusters
  WHERE cluster_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY cluster_id
) AS cluster;
```

Any pointers how I can adapt the above query or write another query to do what I want without resorting to procedural code (if so I would appreciate some pointers about that as well)?

Answer (score 1):

By already in the cluster, I wasn't sure if you meant those picked up by the first cluster or including those you would recursively pick up.

This solution only compares against the original cluster, doesn't try to do based on recursive cluster matching.  That would require a recursive query, and I question if it would yield any better answers.

Also not sure why you decided to go with convexhull to compute your centroid against, I would assume you'd want the true centroid, which can be done against the ST_Collect output.

```
WITH cluster1 AS (
  SELECT
    landmark_id, coordinate,
    ST_ClusterDBSCAN(coordinate, eps := (30 / 111111.0), minpoints := 10) OVER() AS cluster_id
  FROM landmarks 
  WHERE coordinate IS NOT NULL
),
clustered AS ( SELECT * FROM cluster1 WHERE cluster_id IS NOT NULL ) 
clusterall AS (
SELECT 
    l.landmark_id, l.coordinate, c.cluster_id
 FROM landmarks AS l
    CROSS JOIN 
    -- find closest cluster
        LATERAL (SELECT cluster_id 
                FROM clustered AS c 
            ORDER BY  c.coordinate <-> l.coordinate LIMIT 1 ) AS c
    -- only look for landmarks not matched to a cluster
    WHERE l.landmark_id NOT IN(SELECT c.landmark_id FROM clustered AS c)
UNION ALL
SELECT c.landmark_id, c.coordinate, c.cluster_id
    FROM cluster1 
)
SELECT
  cluster.id, cluster.landmark_ids,
  ST_Centroid(cluster.geometry) AS coordinate,
  ST_AsGeoJSON(cluster.geometry) AS geometry
FROM (
  SELECT
    cluster_id AS id,
    array_agg(landmark_id) AS landmark_ids,
    ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(coordinate)) AS geometry
  FROM clusterall
  GROUP BY cluster_id
) AS cluster;
```

Comment: I am not sure if what I want can still be called clustering. Basically it should work like this: ***1)*** From a certain point grow outwards collecting all points x meters or less from that point. ***2)*** From all newly collected points, repeat 1. This will go on till there are no points left within x meters from the latest added points. (this does seem to be where recursion happens) ***3)*** After it is finished I create a convex hull from all collected points. Still have to see which centroid I want to use.